How can I synchronize an online SQL Server database with another offline database in Winforms on .NET Core?
I need to sync a large local SQL Server database to a server database and vice versa. The structure of these two databases is exactly the same. We need to sync data when the user is logged in, or when he syncs data.
I want to do it with a .NET Core Winforms application.
I thought that I can achieve this in a manual way, but I have some issues with this approach:
the database is huge and it will take too long to handle that and this will take along time processing data and it will happen through multiple devices not one.
I tried using a package called SriLibs.DataSync.MSSQLSERVER.Core but it always throws exceptions for data types like date time if the column has the default value which is 01/01/0001 it will throw an exception - can I override this behavior, and if so - how?

Maybe use Log Shipping if you want to keep them absolutely identical?

the database is huge and it will take too long to handle that and this will take along time processing data and it will happen through multiple devices not one. how are you gonna merge the data from different devices into one large database? This sounds a bit like merge replication, are you writing a POS system? Then the answer is, don't

You can use log shipping
or
you could have a timestamp for all your records for latest update or create date. Knowing when you last retrieved the data will provide the info of which new data or changed data to sync.
Now, if you have hard-deletion, then it makes sense to create another database with tablenames and ids to be removed and insert records into this database so you will know later what you need to remove from the copies at syncing and periodically clean up the old records of this database.
or
you could expose an endpoint at the copies and request those end points whenever the primary db has a write operation to be performed.
As you can see, you have multiple possible solutions, you can choose the one which fits your scenario better than the others.

can you explain the log shipping notice that the main Database is big and it will be synced with more than 1 local database for several devices

and for the time stamp for a database this big every time to compare between every local will take long time to process all that data

@mohamedAbdelghany  log shipping can be done with multiple secondary databases, quote from the link I have given in the answer: "SQL Server Log shipping allows you to automatically send transaction log backups from a primary database on a primary server instance to one or more secondary databases on separate secondary server instances.". As about timestamps, if you index this timestamp, then finding records that correspond to it will be fairly quick. It's still time-consuming to load everything into memory if there are lots of things to be loaded, but you cannot not-load it and send it.

@mohamedAbdelghany so you will need to load every changes into memory if you go with the timestamp solution and it would make sense to do it with a cron job, saving the new changes inside a local file in your primary and once that's completed, apply them to your copies. Or use log shipping to solve the same problem. Here's a video about configuring log shipping: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_iQcEnaOgcs
